How to resolve CORS issue in the production for small projects?
I'm creating a productivity tool for myself as a beginner project using zenquotes API. Which is a productivity tool which needs to display a quote on the top of the screen everyday.
The Issue :
1) While developing it and running in my local system, The JSON data is not fetched.
2) In the console, It shows CORS issue.
this is the code
async function getQuote()
{
    try {
        const quote_file=await fetch(`https://zenquotes.io/api/today`);
        const quote = await quote_file.json();
        console.log(quote);
    } 
    catch(err)
    {
        getQuote();
    }
}
getQuote();

what I've been tried :
1) Run the program in the browser using Live Server Extension.
2) Deployed this website in the netlify but in vain.
3) used https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ as prefix for the fetch link that also in vain

Just make sure your server emits CORS headers. If it's not your server, build your own server that calls the API on your behalf.

Just a few quick comments. This issue here is not with how you are calling the API but how that API is handling CORS.
If you look at the headers on the response it looks something like...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 16 Sep 2024 17:59:08 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self';
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Here we are missing the access-control-allow-origin header so Chrome enforces the same origin policy.
Conversely, if you look at another API like https://picsum.photos, it works just fine because they are handling CORS by setting this header and value to  access-control-allow-origin: * to allow requests from any origin (i.e. *).
This often implies that the API should be called server side where you can have control of CORS, like using the cors express middleware.
Alternatively, if you are just playing around trying to run this in your browser you can use a Chrome extension to disable CORS, like this to disable CORS temporarily, and the problem goes away. Just be careful not to enable this for every site.
